# REST API - Create resource and nested resource best practices

Tags: rest, post

I have a question about REST API, especially about resource creation (and nested resources).

Suppose we have the following "GET" routes:

```
GET /recipes/1
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Crepes",
  "ingredients": [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Flour", "quantity": 100},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Milk", "quantity": 15},
    ...
  ]
}

GET /recipes/1/ingredients/1
{
  "name": "Flour",
  "quantity": 100,
  "details": "...",
  ...
}
```

My question is: what is the best practice/design for `POST /recipes`? (Suppose we want to create the previous recipe)

1. we make only 1 call:

```
POST /recipes
body = {
  "name": "Crepes",
  "ingredients": [
    {"name": "Flour", "quantity": 100, ...},
    {"name": "Milk", "quantity": 15, ...}
    ...
  ]
}
```

==> Recipe and ingredients are created at the same time

2. we make 1 call for recipe, and X for ingredients:

```
POST /recipes
body = {
  "name": "Crepes"
}

POST /recipes/1/ingredients
body = {
  "name": "Flour",
  "quantity": 100,
  ...
}

...
```

==> recipe and ingredients are created one after the other

So, what is the best practice/design for resources and nested-resources?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

TL; DR -- yes, you want to send a single request to the server, and permit the server to "create" as many resources as it needs to support future work.

The potentially complicating issue in HTTP is *caching*.  One of the important ideas in [REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) is that it "allows references to be made to a concept before any realization of that concept exists".

Within the context of the web, that means that a client can potentially `GET /recipes/1/ingredients/1` before that resource has a representation.  When the server responds with [404 Not Found](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4), that response is [cacheable](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.3).

Here's an important idea: [cache-invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) has very precise semantics; a successful `POST /recipes` request will invalidate any locally cached copies of the `/recipes` resource, but it will have no effect on cached copies of `/recipes/1` or `/recipes/1/ingredients/1`.

Which means that if you put a general purpose reverse proxy in front of your API, the copies of the different resources at the proxy won't all update together.  Because the different resources aren't invalidating, there are various scenarios in which consumers of multiple resources will see inconsistent information.

The good news is that you, the origin server, control not only the representations of the resources but also the caching meta data.  So you can tune the caching strategy to  the best compromise among the conflicting design pressures.

In practice, you will probably find that bulk create of resources isn't a problem, because there's little reason for a client to fetch a resource before it has been created.  Bulk *updates* are more problematic.